# How to find a single <a href> from a multiple <p> tags and a div class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a question about beautifulsoup.

This is what my divs will look like.

```
<div class="guides__content-container">
  <div class="row row-extra-small text-justify">
     <div class="small-12 columns">
       and then I'll have <p's> that will contain a href
       <p>blalba <a href="test"></a> <a href="test1"><a></p>
       <p>blalba <a href="test2"></a> <a href="test2"><a></p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I have no choice but to differentiate.
How can I get one href for each `p` if there is one?

I started like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Scrapping:
    @staticmethod
    def scrappingDrones(target):
        req = requests.get(target)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
        link = soup.find({"class" : "small-12 columns"})
        print(link)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "h"
    Scrapping.scrappingDrones(url)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the job. I have assumed that you want the first link from each `p` tag. Please let me know if I am wrong.

```
divs = soup.find("div", {"class": "small-12"})
paras = divs.find_all("p")
hrefs = []

for para in paras:
  anchor = para.find("a")
  hrefs.append(anchor.get("href"))

print(hrefs)
```

Output -

```
['test', 'test2']
```